# Does Android support Full-View video recording with wide-angle lens at lower resolutions?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

Assuming I have a new Android phone with a wide-angle back lens that can record with its native Camera App at Full-View mode (so we utilize the sensor as much as possible to not miss any visual information). Assume that the phone can even do that at 60FPS (I guess there are such phones but if not, please correct me).

The question is: Do you think that one could achieve the same footage (maybe using the NDK or CameraX) but at lower resolutions? I mean, keep the Full-View (because I do not want to crop the scene), but just lower proportionally the XY resolution. Is this something that is supported? Or are the settings offered by the native Apps the only possible options that a 3rd party developer can have?

If this can be achieved, how can one identify and use the Camera capabilities to set this up? (i.e. Full-View, Max FPS available for that Full-View and a resolution lower than 0.3MP shaped to that Full-View). Code example is more than welcome.

Comment: "Is this something that is supported?" -- that will vary by device. "Or are the settings offered by the native Apps the only possible options that a 3rd party developer can have?" -- that will depend on what those apps offer. Some will offer a subset of what third-party apps can do. Some will offer *more* than what third-party apps can do, if the device manufacturer is using private APIs that are not part of the Android SDK.

Comment: What information needs to be extracted from the Camera capabilities for one to see how to set this up ideally? The interest is 1st:As bigger field of view as possible, then 2nd: lower resolution for that view as possible (preferably ~0.3MP) and 3rd: 60FPS if possible